# Prepaid SIM card for Austria, with mobile internet and relatively cheap foreign calls

Tags: cellphones, austria

I'm planning to spend about a week in Austria.

I'd like to have mobile internet (mostly for geocaching). 100MB should be enough, however, it would be good to have a bit more. I'd like also to have the possibility to call foreign numbers with reasonable price (my travel friends).

Crucial factor: prepaid card should be ready to use just after purchase, so if internet registration is required, it would be rather no-go (the need to search for Internet Cafe etc.).

Does something like that exists? If not, what would be the nearest hit?

For example, in Germany there's Lebara, with mobile plan for 10 Euro, and very cheap foreign calls, but it requires internet registration. T-Mobile is registered by purchase and ready to go just seconds after, but it has extremely expensive foreign calls. If the situation is similar in Austria, in worst case I would have to choose one of available options, or buy both.

Comment: As of 1 January 2019, all prepaid cards sold in Austria require activation with a photo ID. While this can be done in person in shops owned by the operators, most prepaid SIM cards are sold through tobacco shops or other third-party distributors, which do not offer in-person activation, and you will realistically have to activate them on-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yesss! classic might be what you are looking for.

- The default rate for mobile data is 1 Cent/MB (10 Euro/GB):
  https://www.yesss.at/tarife-wertkarte/yesss%21-classic/7/109
- And they offer 1GB data options for 4 Euros:
  https://www.yesss.at/tarife-wertkarte/daten-paket/7/111
- For international calls you can get the 'yesss! international' option (14 Euros for 14 days). Calls to polish mobile numbers are priced at 0,190 EUR/min when using this option. See:
  https://www.yesss.at/tarife-wertkarte/yesss%21-international/7/116
- According to their FAQ the SIM card can be used immediately after purchase. See section 'Erstbetrieb Ihres yesss! Handys': https://www.yesss.at/tarife-wertkarte/bestellung-%26-aktivierung/7/120
- yesss! SIM cards can be bought at Hofer supermarkets which are popular all over Austria. For store locations please refer to: http://www.hofer.at/at/html/service/store_locator.htm?WT.z_src=main

Comment: Are you associated with this mobile operator?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm not even from Austria.