# Prepaid SIM card for Austrian local calls

Tags: cellphones, austria, mobile-operators, pre-pay

I've just moved to Austria visiting my parents/friends and I am wondering could you help me to find the best deal while I am here approx. for 3-4 months?

I want to make just local calls without data transaction, but I want to call other providers as well tethering, www, etc.

I am curious what is the best deal I checked some service provider, but I don't want to pay 50 euros activation cost + the regular taxes(10 euro/moth) for using the phone for 3 moths.

Ps: My question isn't that [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/prepaid-sim-card-for-austria-with-mobile-internet-and-relatively-cheap-foreign) duplicate. I just want to call several service provider at the cheapest price for a few month without international call or data transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes a lot, so we can't quote prices as they may be outdated pretty quickly for the next visitor.  But one of the best resources for this sort of thing is to look at [prepaidwithdata.wikia](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Austria):

It shows the three major providers there:

- [A1](http://www.a1.net/)
- [T-Mobile](http://www.t-mobile.at/)
- [3 (Drei)](http://www.drei.at/)

and that'd be your best starting point - looking at the sites for those and seeing what the best deal is for you in your situation. Everyone is different in their requirements.